# Getting and ordering the data used on a GBM object on R

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, gbm

I have a GBM object in R with the underlying data saved on it and I'm having troubles using that data. The problem is that when I run `x<-gbmobject$data$x.order` and `y<-gbmobject$data$y` I'm not getting the `y` values ordered in the same way as in `x`, in other words the response of the 1st observation of `x` is **NOT** the 1st observation in `y`. It seems that one of them is shuffled or something like that. Does anyone know how can I do to match the responses in `y` with the correct observations of `x`?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `recons_gbm <- reconstructGBMdata(gbmobject)`. This should do the trick :)

Comment: Thanks! that was perfect!